# VisualVM Profiling tab missing for Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, profiling, visualvm, jvisualvm, memory-profiling

I am Running Tomcat 6.0.29
Java Visual Machine use default is not checked and the  location is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Running VisualVM with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\jvisualvm.exe`

Tomcat doesn't show up as a local application and I can load it as a "remote" connection using JMX, but I don't get the Profiling tab.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Tomcat is running as 'Windows service', am I right? If so, you have two options:

1. Run VisualVM as Windows service too. See [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as) post for more info.
2. Get newer version of VisualVM (JDK 1.6.0_29 is three years old) and use CPU Sampler - it will work over JMX connection and in most cases provides enough information to diagnose the problem.